# How to copy each column in a separate file

Tags: java, file

I have a txt file that contains 24 columns separated with \t. The first column contains words and the other 23 columns contain int (0 or 1). **I need to put each column in a separate file**

For example:

file.txt

```
xyz 0   1
abc 0   1
```

the resulting files would be:

file 1:

```
0
0
```

file 2:

```
1
1
```

The code is as follows:

```
for (int i=24; i>0; i--){
            //copy the last word (column) in list
            for (String str: list) {
                String ch = str.substring(str.length() - 1);
                col_list.add(ch);
            }

            //write the column in file
            FileWriter write = new FileWriter(+i+".txt"); 
            for(String str1: col_list) {
                write.write(str1+"\n");
            }
            write.close();
            col_list = new ArrayList<String>();

            //remove last column from list
            for(String str2: list) {
                str2.substring(str2.length()-3, str2.length()-1);

            }
        }
```

The result files contain only the content of the last column

file 1:

```
1
1
```

file 2:

```
1
1
```

Comment: Your comment is correct at `copy the last char (column) in list` (you want more than the last char).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, that's true! Thank you. I corrected the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about going for it this way? Change num_files to 24 and you should be good to go.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
class Test {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        File myFile = new File("Test.txt");
        try {
            int num_files = 3;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
            String list[];
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                list = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");
                for (int i = 0; i < num_files; i++) {
                    FileWriter write = new FileWriter((i + 1) + ".txt", true); //you want to open it in append mode
                    write.write(list[i] + "\n");
                    write.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Input and Output Files

[image: Input File]

[image: Output Files]

Let me know if this solves your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For the example above, it gives me only 4 files. The first 3 files contain the last line and the fourth file is empty.

Comment: @AsmaMekki I am not sure if I understand the comment. I have updated my answer to include the Test.txt and the output files. You gotta change num_files=24 (if the number of columns on each line is 24).